# How to use handlebars with webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, handlebars.js, webpacker, webpack-handlebars-loader

I have a rails 5.1 app which makes use of the webpacker gem. My package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "^3.0.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.0.10",
    "handlebars-loader": "^1.6.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

And my webpack/environment.js file is as follows:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.plugins.set(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
);

environment.loaders.set('Handlebars', {
  test: /\.hbs$/,
  use: 'handlebars-loader'
});

module.exports = environment;
```

if I create a foo.hbs file in app/javascript/templates then I can successfully compile that template using the following code:

```
const template = require("templates/foo.hbs");
const context = {name: "Fred", age: 5};
const html    = template(context);
```

But the part that I'm having difficulty with is how to add handlebars helpers. I would like to have a folder app/javascript/handlebars-helpers and place helper functions in there but I'm unsure how to configure this. 
handlebars-loader has documentation that suggests how you can specify a helpers directory: https://github.com/pcardune/handlebars-loader/blob/master/examples/helperDirs/webpack.config.js but it isn't clear to me how I would add this to environment.js for webpacker.

Answer (score 1):

after some experimenting I was able to get this working by changing my webpack/environment.js file to read as follows:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.plugins.set(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery'
  })
);

environment.loaders.set('Handlebars', {
  test: /\.hbs$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'handlebars-loader',
    query: {
      knownHelpersOnly: false,
      helperDirs: [
        path.resolve(__dirname, "../..", "app/javascript/handlebars-helpers")
      ]
    }
  }
});

module.exports = environment;
```

Now I am able to place handlebars helper methods in my app/javascript/handlebars-helpers directory and they get automatically picked up.

Comment: I did exact same steps, but unable to make it work.  Will you be able to share code from your helper file?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it working like this in the latest Rails version:

1.Add necessary dependencies

```
yarn add handlebars
yarn add handlebars-loader
```

2.Register your handlebars loader

```
 // config/webpack/loaders/handlebars.js
 module.exports = {
   test: /\.hbs$/,
   loader: 'handlebars-loader'
 }


 // config/webpack/environment.js  
 const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
 const handlebars = require('./loaders/handlebars')

 environment.loaders.prepend('handlebars', handlebars)
 module.exports = environment
```

Rails Webpacker has pretty nice documentation about loaders, check it out [here](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/webpack.md#loaders)